# Unlocking a locked active directory account

Tags: java, active-directory, jndi

I want to unlock a locked active directory account using jndi. It is usually done using by changing the user account attribute as far I know. However I am unable to get the correct combination of its various options.

Answer (score 2):

Set the lockoutTime attribute to 0 and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Can you tell me how to set the lockoutTime attribute? I am able to display the value of lockoutTime attribute.

Comment: @Raja Roy with the DirContext.setAttribute() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use PowerShell:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory;
Unlock-ADAccount <Username>;
```

Replace  with the actual username.

Answer (score 0):

```
ChaiUser chai_user = chaiProvider.getEntryFactory().newChaiUser(userdn);
boolean islocked = chai_user.isLocked();
chai_user.unlockPassword();
```